# PHP Building Array via Hidden element

Tags: php, post, web

I'm trying to implement some code that keeps adding to an array every time my page is submitted. I want to do this using serialize/unserialize method. For some reason my array simply adds one item and just changes that item every time I submit the form.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $array_var=array("Name"=>"Doe","Karma"=>"45","Date"=>"2012-08-30");
?>

<form action="testtestmain.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="str_var" name="str_var" value="<?php print base64_encode(serialize($array_var)) ?>">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['str_var'])) {
    $str_var=$_POST['str_var'];
    $str_var=unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['str_var']));
    $str_var[]=$_POST['name'];

    foreach ($str_var as $cur) {
        echo $cur."<br>";
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP values aren't saved between requests, remember HTTP is a stateless protocol. Thus each time you submit and refresh the page the array will be empty.

If you want to keep the data you'll need to save it in either: a cookie, a file, the session or a database.

Alternatively you can resend the full array via the hidden field, by moving the PHP up so to correctly populating the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

<?php

$str_var = isset($_POST['str_var']) ? unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['str_var'])) : [];

if(isset($_POST['str_var']))
{
    $str_var[] = $_POST['name'];
}

?>

<form action="testtestmain.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="str_var" name="str_var" value="<?php print base64_encode(serialize($str_var)) ?>">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<?php
foreach($str_var as $cur)
{
    echo $cur."<br>";
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey  Freid  is there no way to save it in a hidden element as an input?

Comment: Ah sorry, I miss understood what you are try to do. I've updated my answer ^.

Comment: I think you understood it correctly the first time I think i need to use a session or a database thanks you